# Error on converting from unsigned int to float

Tags: c++, floating-point, type-conversion

Background: I have some elements in a record, where some elements can be float, unsigned int or unsigned long long. So, I though to use float as a common value to return from a function that reads those elements.

However, I am seeing this strange error on converting from unsigned int to float. On printing the value, it gets changed. How can I avoid it? Should I not return float from this function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  unsigned int  myU = numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
  cout<<" myU is "<<myU<<'\n'; //correct
  float myF = (float) myU;
  cout<<" back To Long "<<(unsigned long long ) myF<<'\n'; //error?
  cout<<" back To unsigned int "<<(unsigned int ) myF<<'\n'; //error?
  cout<<" to Float Without Fixed "<<(float) myU<<'\n';//not clear, so have to use fixed
  cout<<" to Float With Fixed "<<fixed<<(float) myU<<'\n';//error?
  cout<<" difference "<<myF-myU<<'\n'; //error?
  cout<<" myU+32 "<<myU+32<<'\n'; //-1+32=31 ==> understandable
}
```

Output with gcc 4.6.3:

```
 myU is 4294967295
 back To Long 4294967296
 back To unsigned int 0
 to Float Without Fixed 4.29497e+09
 to Float With Fixed 4294967296.000000
 difference 1.000000
 myU+32 31
```

Comment: A 32 bit [float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) can't have enough precision to store the _exact_ value of a 32 bit unsigned int (or worse a long long) because the significand precision is only 24 bits. Try using a double instead, but not for long long ints.

Comment: note: the "back To unsigned int" line causes undefined behaviour becaues the value is out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number `4294967295` in `float (32-bit IEEE 754)` is represented as follows:

```
0       10011111      00000000000000000000000
sign    exponent      mantissa
(+1)    (2^32)        (1.0)
```

The rule for converting it back to an integer (or long in this case) is:

```
sign * (2^exponent) * mantissa
```

and the result would be `4294967296` which is in appropriate size to fill `long long` for you but too big to be fit in `unsigned int` so you will get `0` for `unsigned int` conversion.

Note that the problem is the limitation of representing large numbers with float for example `4294967295` and `4294967200` both are representing the same bits when they are stored as floats.

Comment: @M.M thanks for the note, I corrected that and yes the numbers even between 4294967200 and 4294967295 are not representable

Comment: OK. The point I'm trying to make is that 4294967295 is not represented like that (in fact it is not representable at all); the representation you showed is one possibility that might arise if you *try to* represent that number.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you are seeing, is that a [floating point type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) only provides a limited precision of its fraction part, which of course is natural since it can only hold so much information.

Now when you convert from `unsigned int` to `float`, the number you are using is too long to fit into the fraction part. Now that some precision was lost and you convert back to an integer format it may differ. To `unsigned long long`, the result is just one bigger, but in the conversion to `unsigned int`, you see an overflow happpening.